Highlight editable cells/columns in DT
I have a Shiny App with a DataTable that allows the user to see the margin made on various products while allowing edits on the buying and selling prices to recalculate said margin. To make obvious that those columns can be edited, I would like the editable cells and columns to appear like inputs from the start instead of having to doublecklick on them.
Here is what I would like to have displayed at launch :

And what I currently work with :

Below is a reproducible exemple :
# Libraries

library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)


# JS code for Keyboard shortcuts
# Allow to use arrow-keys and Enter to edit and confirm new values in cells

js <- c(
  "table.on('key', function(e, datatable, key, cell, originalEvent){",
  "  var targetName = originalEvent.target.localName;",
  "  if(key == 13 && targetName == 'body'){",
  "    $(cell.node()).trigger('dblclick.dt');",
  "  }",
  "});",
  "table.on('keydown', function(e){",
  "  var keys = [9,13,37,38,39,40];",
  "  if(e.target.localName == 'input' && keys.indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1){",
  "    $(e.target).trigger('blur');",
  "  }",
  "});",
  "table.on('key-focus', function(e, datatable, cell, originalEvent){",
  "  var targetName = originalEvent.target.localName;",
  "  var type = originalEvent.type;",
  "  if(type == 'keydown' && targetName == 'input'){",
  "    if([9,37,38,39,40].indexOf(originalEvent.keyCode) > -1){",
  "      $(cell.node()).trigger('dblclick.dt');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});"
)


modServ_EdiTable <- function(id, data_initialisation) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    # initialise the reactive data object for the table
    data <- reactiveVal()
    observe(data(data_initialisation()))
    
    # render the table
    output$dummyDT <- renderDT({
      datatable(
        data(),
        selection = 'none', 
        editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(0:1, 4))),
        callback = JS(js),
        extensions = 'KeyTable',
        options = list(keys = TRUE)
      )
    })
    
    # update the underlying data
    observeEvent(input$dummyDT_cell_edit, {
      data(
        editData(data(), input$dummyDT_cell_edit) %>%  
          mutate(Margin = round(`Selling Price` - `Buying Price`, 2))
      )
    })
    
    # return the data as a reactive
    return(data)
  })
}


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dummyData <- reactive({
    tibble(
      Material = c("Lead", "Tin", "Iron", "Copper", "Mercury", "Silver", "Gold"),
      `Buying Price` = c(12.2, 10.3, 8, 5.6, 7.5, 22.9, 50),
      `Selling Price` = c(18, 15, 12, 10, 11, 40, 100),
      Margin = round(`Selling Price` - `Buying Price`, 2)
    )
  })
  
  modServ_EdiTable("dummyId", data_initialisation = dummyData)
  
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {stopApp()})
}


modUI_EdiTable <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  card(DTOutput(ns("dummyDT")))
}

ui <- page_navbar(
  nav_panel(title = "dummyPanel", modUI_EdiTable(id = "dummyId"))
)

shinyApp(ui, server)


This is what you probably want: https://rstudio.github.io/shiny/reference/numericInput.html


I suppose you mean replacing every cell by a numericInput with its own ID while initializing it's values ? I considered this option (and already did something similar for a more complex table) but I was wondering if there wasn't a simpler approach to the problem, as I will have to use it for a table with hundreds of rows while using the results to calculate the Margin in the same row
